# what does print() do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for i in range(len(grid[0])):
    for j in range(len(grid)):
        print(grid[j][i], end='')
    print()
```

I am a complete beginner in Python. Using python 3.6. I understand the code. The only thing I don't get it what does `print()` do in the last line?

```
print()
```

It's not printing a new line because `'end = ''` is already doing it.

Comment: ... it prints a newline

Comment: without it, all the output ends up on the same line

Comment: ... also, this is almost as inefficient way to print that grid as Pythonically possible.

Comment: prints just a newline.

Comment: It's trivial to just run the code with and without the last `print()` to see what the difference is

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks guys.

Comment: @zwer note that it is printing `grid` transposed. Which also can be done in more elegant way.

Comment: Just realized it `print`s a heart shape <3, nice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`end = ''` makes it *not* print a newline character for the prints in your nested for loop. The default kwarg for `end` is the newline character, `\n`.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print

So the print at the end *does* print a newline at the end of that iteration of the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

It is printing the newline. `end=''` is causing that print statement NOT to print a new line.

Comment: Oh! Guess I messed it up. Thank you .